# Remove Class and children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to inject some Jquery into my browser to remove `<a></a>`
here is my code

```
<div class="fc-event-container">
  <a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" 
     style="top: 0px; bottom: -463.05px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%;">
    <div class="fc-content">
      <div class="fc-time" data-full="12:00 AM - 12:00 AM" data-start=" ">
        <span> </span>
      </div>
      <div class="fc-title">26% discount</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fc-bg"></div>
    <div class="fc-resizer fc-end-resizer"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to remove the `<a> </a>` but I have failed consistently to do so.  I have tried different apis on the jquery documentation for example.

```
$( "a" ).removeClass( "fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" );

("a").("fc-time-grid-event.fc-v-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end fc-draggable.fc-resizable" ).remove();

(.'fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable').remove();
```

Comment: FullCalender probably adds those classes dynamically some time after DOM ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here some information how jQuery selectors work: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

You write you want to remove the a tag, this would do just that:

```
$(".fc-event-container a").remove();
```

In case you want to remove the classes:

```
$(".fc-event-container a").removeClass("fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable");
```

In comments there is another request:

> ```
> Is there a way to remove the whole <a> based on the title seen
> here <div class="fc-title">26% discount</div>? I want to delete <a>
> when the title contains 26%.
> ```

```
$(".fc-title:contains('26%')").closest('a').remove();
```

Comment: He wants to remove the class from the a tag, not the tag itself.

Comment: In the question he states: "I want to remove the <a> </a>". His code on the other hand does indeed what you say.

Comment: Ah yes. You're right, it seems his question contradicts itself, as he says on the first line that "he wants to remove a class", very confusing...

Comment: Oh true that, updated the answer to include that variation.

Comment: Thanks this helped alot! Is there a way also to remove the whole <a> based on the title seen here <div class="fc-title">26% discount</div>? Si I want to delete <a> when twhich has 26%.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to remove the `<a>` element itself then you should be using the remove() function.

One way would be to target the parent div and then remove the `<a>` element.

```
$('.fc-event-container').find('a').remove();
```

Here you are targeting the parent div, then your are finding the `<a>` element using the find() function and then you are removing that `<a>` element.

You can use the same method to remove the classes on an element.

```
$('.fc-event-container').find('a').removeClass('[class name]')
```

You can remove one class or multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is totally wrong. This is the corrected one and it doesn't work as it is not sensible:

```
$("a").removeClass("fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable");
$("a.fc-time-grid-event.fc-v-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end fc-draggable.fc-resizable" ).remove();
$(".fc-time-grid-event.fc-v-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable.fc-resizable").remove();
```

Updated code, that could probably work:

```
$("a[class^='fc']").remove();
```

Comment: Still has mistakes... did you test this? Also a good idea to say what you changed when the code is so lengthy

Comment: Even if the code is "correct", its not gona work, first you remove the classes from the anchor tag, and then you try to retrieve that with jquery.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, I did.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I just checked the syntax. The code makes no sense.

Comment: The second line does nothing since in the first one you have all the classes are removed. The same happens with the last line.

Comment: @sailens Updated answer.

Comment: your updated variant will also remove the div container around the a tag, well might be what is wished...

Comment: @user5542121 Updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with selecting element. Try this.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.fc-event-container a').removeClass('fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable');
});
```

Since you have only one a tag in `.fc-event-container`, it should be fine.

Also see below for example.
https://jsfiddle.net/Ohsik/wrx4Lpr9/2/